# What is a reasonable year datatype in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, types

Two possibilities come into my mind:

- `NUMBER(4)`
- `DATE`

Pro `NUMBER(4)`:

- No duplicate entries possible if specified as UNIQUE
- Easy arithmetic (add one, subtract one)

Con `NUMBER(4)`:

- No Validation (e.g. negative numbers)

Pro `DATE`:

- Validation

Con `DATE`:

- Duplicate entries are possible ('2013-06-24', '2013-06-23', ...)
- Not so easy arithmetic (add one = ADD_MONTHS(12))

As additional requirement the column gets compared with the current year `EXTRACT (YEAR FROM SYSDATE)`. In my opinion `NUMBER(4)` ist the better choice. What do you think, is there another option I have missed?

Comment: If you use `NUMBER(4,0)` it's fairly easy to write a CHECK constraint to avoid invalid input. BTW, I'm not aware of calendars that have a zero year but they all have negative ones ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restrict a `date` column to only have one entry per year if you want to, with a function-based index:

```
create unique index uq_yr on <table> (trunc(<column>, 'YYYY'));
```

Trying to insert two dates in the same year would give you an ORA-00001 error. Of course, if you don't want the rest of the date then it may be unhelpful or confusing to hold it, but on the other hand there may be secondary info you want to keep (e.g. if you're recording that an annual audit happened, holding the full date might not hurt anything). You could also have a virtual column (from 11g) that holds the `trunc` value for easier manipulation, perhaps.

You could also use an `interval year(4) to month` data type, and insert using `numtoyminterval(2013, 'year')`, etc. You could do interval arithmetic to add and subtract years, and `extract` to get the year back out as a number. That would probably be more painful than using a `date` though, overall.

If you're really only interested in the year (and you are not holding the month in a different column!) then a number is probably going to be simplest, with a check constraint to make sure it's a sensible number - `number(4)` doesn't stop you inserting `2.013` when you meant `2,013` (though you need to be converting from a string to hit that, and not have an NLS parameter mismatch), which would be truncated to just `2`.

Answer (score 3):

You've quite well summed up the pros/cons.

Provided that you name clearly your field so that it's easy to understand that it contains a year information, I would go with a `NUMBER(4)` for simplicity & storing no more or less than what is necessary. And even if there is no validation, IMO negative years are valid :)

Comment: +1 for confirming this choice. I'm going to do it this way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case you might also consider building a one-off date (dimension) table and linking to a specific row via ID. That way, you have access to more information which you could later add to the dinemsion table (leap year etc.) and the entries in your dimension can be validated on creation.